# Check if NSString is only letters

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring

What's the best way to make sure an NSString contains only the letters a-z and A-Z.

I've tried the following code but it's not working for some reason:

```
NSString *myegex = @"[A-Za-z]";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myregex];
if (![emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.initials.text])  {
     // print error
     return;
}
```

Comment: What does "it's not working for some reason" mean?  Is it failing to compile? Is it throwing a run-time exception?  Is there a compile-time error?  Is it producing unintended results (what are the results for what input and how does this compare to intended results)? Is it launching missiles?  What's happening?

Answer (score 14):

You can do it in a simpler way by creating your own `NSCharacterSet` then checking the string against that set with `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`

```
//Create character set
NSCharacterSet *validChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];

//Invert the set
validChars = [validChars invertedSet];

//Check against that
NSRange  range = [myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:validChars];
if (NSNotFound != range.location) {

 //invalid chars found

}
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd use [`+[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet) instead of hard-coding all the letters.

Comment: @zpasternack Well, I saw his string named `emailTest` and figured he is trying to validate an email address that can obviously contain more that only letters. It is basically a hack to avoid complicated regex, although in this case the OP may need exactly that.

Comment: @zpasternack letterCharacterSet DOES include the period punctuation and other marks.  =(  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet

Comment: @jungledev Doesn't include period or punctuation; includes Marks, which [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/nonBaseCharacterSet) define as "...all legal Unicode characters with a non-spacing priority greater than 0. Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as modifiers of base characters."

Comment: @zpasternack, I understand what is explained in the docs (which I referred to in order to figure out that it doesn't exclude periods), but in actual use, periods are NOT excluded, so be warned.  Perhaps it's an Obj-C bug?  I don't know.  I was working on the CodeEval "Roller Coaster" algorithm challenge (https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/156/), and spent a long time debugging why my solution didn't work.  It didn't work because letterCharacterSet doesn't exclude periods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Objective-C regex engine works, but you can leverage anchors `^` and `$` to check if your string starts and finishes with letters by using this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

Using your code, would be:

```
NSString *myegex = @"^[A-Za-z]+$";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myregex];
if (![emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.initials.text])  {
     // print error
     return;
}
```