# Validate Entry In TextField

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield, textfield

I have a textfield which allows the user to input text and saves this text to a variable and stores it in user defaults. I need the input to be a string therefore I need the textfield to detect the input as being anything but a string. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you not consider a string in a textField?

Comment: Everything in that text field is a string. You'll need to determine your own rules about what you consider a valid string and compare against those.

Comment: I've rephrased the question name to clarify; I need to essentially validate the input to check it is a string (cannot be integers/doubles such as 5 or 5.3)

Comment: You need only alphabetical characters in your textfield ?

Comment: yes it needs to be alphabetical @Rajat as the textfield is used to enter a name. BTW the textfielf is in a alert controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let characterSet = NSCharacterSet.letters
    return (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil)
}
```

make sure you have set `delegate` for your `textfield` properly

Comment: I know this solution gets used over and over but this is really a terribly inefficient way to verify the characters in the string.

Comment: @rmaddy what is the issue in this solution. I am a noob :)

Comment: It's very inefficient to split the entire string into an array and then rejoin all of the array elements back into a string and then compare the two strings just to see if the original string contains valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope it helps you.

```
func updateSaveButtonState() {
    let text = titleTextField.text ?? ""
    saveButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty
}


@IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    updateSaveButtonState()
}

@IBAction func returnPressed(_ sender: UITextField) {
    titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below code: swift 4.0

```
func validateOnlyLetters(text: String) -> Bool {
    let characterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    return (text.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) == nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

by default, textField.text property is a string. 
if you don't want the users to enter any numbers, you may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699407/check-if-nsstring-is-only-letters) to vaidate the input before saving into userdefaults.

another post in Swift - [How can I check if a string contains letters in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520618/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-letters-in-swift)

```
let letters = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()

let phrase = "Test case"
let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters)

// range will be nil if no letters is found
if let test = range {
    println("letters found")
}
else {
   println("letters not found")
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exaclty what I need; to validate the input before saving. The post is in Objective C however I am using swift and don't understand it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520618/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-letters-in-swift

Comment: refer this post